# Hibernate, Nhibernate Eager Loading Not working (ignored)

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

All,

Using nhibernate 5.x, asp.net 4.6.1

I have the following association:

Project Address => Project => Region

I want to query project address and eagerly load project and project region (and also country which is on the project), ... the project is eagerly loaded but the project region is not! When I inspect in the debugger the Region on the project is a proxy type. I tried various queries without success:

```
 var address = session.CreateCriteria<ProjectAddress>()
                .Add(Expression.Eq(Projections.Id(), addressId))
                .SetFetchMode("Project", NHibernate.FetchMode.Join)
                .SetFetchMode("Project.Region", NHibernate.FetchMode.Join)
                .SetFetchMode("Project.Country", NHibernate.FetchMode.Join)
                .UniqueResult<ProjectAddress>();
```

and

```
var address = session.Session.Query<ProjectAddress>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == addressId)
                .Fetch(x => x.Project)
                .ThenFetch(p => p.Region)
                .ThenFetch(p => p.Country)
                .Single();
```

I've done this in other queries and it works, why its not working in this case is beyond me. There's nothing special about the mapping here (Project=>Region). My mapping:

```
[ManyToOne(Column = "region_id",
               ClassType = typeof(Region),
                NotNull = false)]
    public virtual Region Region
    {
        get { return _region; }
        set { _region = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out the problem. The reason why Project.Region, Project.Country were proxies is because prior to loading the project address I have loaded a Project into the session somewhere else (without eager loading Region/Country). 
So, after that I load the project address and hibernate doesn't fetch the project (hence ignoring my fetch strategy) again but uses the cached Project in the session.
This can be verified by calling Session.EvictAll() before loading my project address.

Is there a way in hibernate to explicitly tell to execute fully query (without using Evict())?

Comment: What you see is expected and required behavior. NHibernate always guarantees that a session yields the same object reference for an entity it has already loaded (unless evicted). So, if you lazy load your entity first, then query it eagerly, it will still yield you a proxy for the entity. But that proxy will normally be already initialized, and will not cause any additional lazy-load. Having received a proxy does not mean the eager loading has not be done. Check this by using `NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized`.

Comment: "Hibernate always guarantees that a session yields the same object reference for an entity it has already loaded" - Yes, I recalled that after I found the problem. To resolve my issue I implemented Unproxy() method that traverses object graph and loads all associations eagerly. Then I could stick the entity in the view state and have it serialized properly (not using the proxy classes). As for the second comment about session, and unit of work pattern, I am using the adopted Session/Request model and this will sometimes cause issues like this. Its not wrong, just have to be careful.